# Installing NGINX (newbie)

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to install Tengine which is based off of Nginx from their [Github page](https://github.com/alibaba/tengine):

The page says, "To install Tengine, just follow these three steps:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

Can someone tell me the actual first step on how to download Tengine to my server so I can install it?

I'll be using Amazon's Linux AMI.

Thank you so much! 
- Jennifer

Comment: Read some tutorial [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation) or watch some videos there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install you can use:

```
wget -c http://tengine.taobao.org/download/tengine.tar.gz
```

Then, access the folder to which you downloaded (/usr/local/nginx), and find the configure file and excecute it:

```
./configure
```

After that you can compile it :)

```
make
```

Also, you can check more documentation here:
http://tengine.taobao.org/documentation.html

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: The `wget`  is probably not getting the source code from the `github` repository

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest code from github just execute

```
git clone https://github.com/alibaba/tengine.git
```

After that change to directory *tengine/*

```
cd tengine/
```

and start

```
./configure && make && make install
```